# OpenGL 2 slowness

Tags: python, opengles, golang

The Raspberry Pi 3b+ runs my OpenGL 2.1 program **very slowly**, with a frame rate of around 2 fps. How is this possible, when Python/Pyglet can render (using OpenGL, I suppose) much faster than this? And how may I fix it? The OpenGL 2.1 program I speak of is a little app I made using a 2d game library that utilizes OpenGL 2.1 written in Go.

Comment: The Pi GPU implements **openGL ES**, which is a *subset* of GL, so straight GL code will not get hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For accelerated OpenGL 2.x support, you need to enable the (non-default-on-raspbian) open source graphics driver.  Look for "experimental GL driver" in raspi-config.

Comment: Awesome. Thankyou **very** much!